# Es mejor un archivo JSON por imagen o un JSON para todas las imagenes?

Tags: json, date, imagen

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de crear un editor de texto en qt c++, y estoy creando la función de edición de imágenes. El dilema es cuando que método debería usar para almacenar las imágenes,pensaba por medio de datos binarios base64y guardar los datos en un archivo JSON, pero ahora no se si debería crear un JSON por imagen o guardar todos los datos en un JSON?

Comment: y porque no guardar las imágenes como imágenes?

Comment: el problema es que si quiero que se visualize en el cuadro de texto, tengo que enlazar un enlace del archivo (ya que guardo en formato rtk [que usa html]), y lo estoy  comprimiendo para guardar espacio, pero ya me encuentro en el dile si me complico y meto todo en un json, o dejo un json por cada archivo?

Comment: Yo no he hecho nada parecido, pero supongo que si guardas todas las imágenes en un solo JSON puede darse el caso que tengas muchas imágenes y pesadas, por lo que abrir todo este texto puede dar problemas, en cambio ir abriendo de un json con un sola imagen y luego cerrar el archivo liberaras la memoria.